# Does a polynomial in two variables which establishes a bijection between

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials

Does a polynomial in two variables which establishes a bijection between the
points with nonnegative integer coordinates and natural numbers exist? porve it

Comment: Could you show us your attempt(s) at solving this?

Comment: i think the anser is P(x,y)=x+y. but i dont know how to prove it or if i get the anser.

Comment: @heyThere: That is not a bijection -- $P(1,2)=P(2,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard "zig-zag" bijection $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ (which corresponds to enumerating the pairs in order of increasing sum, and between pairs with the same sum in order of the first element) is polynomial.

I will leave it to you to derive the precise coefficients (which will depend on whether $0\in\mathbb N$ for you anyway) -- you will need to use the formula for the triangular numbers $\frac{n(n+1)}2$, which can give you the number of pairs with a *smaller* sum than the one you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

A quadratic bijection is
$$f(x, y) = \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2} + x$$
which is called the 'Cantor pairing function' (see [this](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/cantorpairing.pdf)).

This probably answers your question, but for more information, you can [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/325241/140607) any [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/187758/140607) these [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/132834/140607) (incidentally all by the same user).